# Python - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, attributes, findall, nonetype

I have written my first bit of python code to scrape a website.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

c = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kitco.com/kitco-gold-index.html').read())
table = soup.find('table', id="datatable_main")
rows = table.findAll('tr')[1:]

for tr in rows:
   cols = tr.findAll('td')
   text = []
   for td in cols:
       text.append(td.find(text=True))
   c.writerow(text)
```

When I test it locally in my ide called pyCharm it works good but when I try it out on my server which runs CentOS, I get the following error:

```
domainname.com [~/public_html/livegold]# python scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 8, in <module>
    rows = table.findAll('tr')[:]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

I'm guessing I don't have a module installed remotely, I've been hung up on this for two days any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: @karthikr: It's not the tr that's the problem; he's getting an exception trying to call `table.findAll` because _table_ is already `None`.

Comment: To debug this, try printing out `soup`, and `soup.find('table')`, and `soup.find('table', id="datatable_main")`, and see what all of them look like.

Comment: Also, I notice that the line in your traceback and the line in your source don't match. Is it possible that you uploaded an older (and not yet working) version of your script to the server box?

Comment: Abarnert, thank you very much for your help. Thanks to your trouble shooting suggestions I am able to pinpoint the problem to soup.find('table',id="datatable_main") - when I printed this out the word "None" appeared.

Comment: So now you have to figure out _why_ it's `None`. Look at `soup`, and see if there's a `table` whose id is `datatable_main`. If not, obviously any attempt to `find` it should, and will, return `None`—either you're reading the wrong data, or you've got the wrong structure for the data. On the other hand, if you _do_ see it, then you have to figure out why the `find` isn't finding it. Either way, finding out which it is has to be the first step to debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring any errors that could occur in `urllib2.urlopen`, if for some reason you are getting an error trying to get that page on your server, which you don't get testing locally you are effectively passing in an empty string (`''`) or a page you don't expect (such as a 404 page) to `BeautifulSoup`.

Which in turn makes your `soup.find('table', id="datatable_main")` return `None` since the document is something you don't expect.

You should either make sure you can get the page you are trying to get on your server, or handle exceptions properly.

Comment: It's also possible that the `find` returns `None` because it's passed a 404 error page, or some perfectly valid page that doesn't happen to have a table with id `datatable_main`, or all kinds of other possibilities.

Comment: @abarnert indeed, that is most likely what is happening, since after re-reading the urllib2 docs it seems it **always** raises `URLError` if it has an actual error (haven't used urllib2 in a while). Edited it in.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I have read this site for years this is my first question. Locally the script works great, I just did a small test and was able to print the kitco url in my terminal. I believe I am missing a module of some sort and "findAll" is not being recognized. I obviously am a very amateur programmer and appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Also, there is indeed an  table with the id of datatable_main on the page thus why the script works locally.

Comment: @SeymourDucats try looking at what `urllib2.urlopen` returns on your server.

Comment: <function urlopen at 0xb72dc8ec>

Comment: I did a small test and was able to print the html of the kitco url to my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `table` with `id` `datatable_main` in the page that the script read.

Try printing the returned page to the terminal - perhaps your script is failing to contact the web server?  Sometimes hosting services prevent outgoing HTTP connections.

Comment: Thanks - I did this

>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kitco.com/kitco-gold-index.html').read())
>>> print soup

and the page was returned in the terminal